# Where should I apply the SSL certificate?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat

I just bought a positive SSL for my company's staging server.

We Apache web server and tomcat installed on the server.

I'm not an expert but I saw some  settings in httpd.conf file that has url like this:

```
ajp://example.com/uk:8005
```

In this case, would I need to install SSL in tomcat or Apache?

PS. In our production server where an ssl is already installed and working I can see SSL settings in httpd.conf file (I wish I can ask the person who set this up but they are not here anymore..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJP does not work with ssl.

Install the Certificate in the Apache Webserver.

Comment: Tomcat http works fine too.